# Saved username/password appear in the wrong fields on Firefox

Tags: html, firefox

I have this strange bug on Firefox, not Chrome (both updated).

On the login page of my website, the fields are :

```html
<div class="input text required">
    <label for="ArchUtilisateurUsername">Identifiant :</label>
    <input name="data[ArchUtilisateur][username]" id="ArchUtilisateurUsername" type="text">
</div>
<div class="input password">
    <label for="ArchUtilisateurPassword">Mot de passe :</label>
    <input name="data[ArchUtilisateur][password]" id="ArchUtilisateurPassword" type="password">
</div>
```

Then on another page, I have a form to create "readers" accounts, which are different than users accounts. It uses read ID and password as login informations, but in this form, both aren't next to each others.
So I have this :

```html
<div class="group-content">
    <div id="DivFieldLecteurFormCompteActif" class="input checkbox ">
        <input name="data[LecteurForm][compte_actif]" value="" type="hidden">
        <input name="data[LecteurForm][compte_actif]" id="FieldLecteurFormCompteActif" value="1" type="checkbox">
        <label for="FieldLecteurFormCompteActif">Compte actif</label>
    </div>
    <div id="DivFieldLecteurFormPassword" class="input password ">
        <label for="FieldLecteurFormPassword">Mot de passe</label>
        <input name="data[LecteurForm][password]" id="FieldLecteurFormPassword" autocomplete="off" type="password">
    </div>
    <div id="DivFieldLecteurFormPasswordConfirm" class="input password ">
        <label for="FieldLecteurFormPasswordConfirm">Confirmation</label>
        <input name="data[LecteurForm][password_confirm]" id="FieldLecteurFormPasswordConfirm" autocomplete="off" type="password">
    </div>
</div>
```

The strange problem is, if a user validates the Firefox's "save my login datas" popup when he logs in the website, when he opens the "reader" form,

- the "password" field is filled with the user's password
- the first previous text input field to the password field is filled with the user's username

Starting to the password field : if the previous one is a checkbox, select, radio, it's ignored and go further. If I remove the input field with the username from my source, when I reload the page it's the next previous input field that get the username.

All seems to be linked to the password field :

- Login form and Reader form have different password field names, but it's still doing this
- If I delete this password field in the code, after reloading the "password confirm" field is filled with the user password
- If I delete both, the user password appear nowhere, so do the username.
- If I change the password field type from "password" to "text" and reload, the password doesn't appear in this field but in "confirm password". And no longer appear (nor the username) if I do this to both.

The last point seems to confirm that (in my case at least), when Firefox has a saved username/password for a website, it tries to fill the infos to the first password-type field he finds, then fills the first previous text-type field.
As you can see in the code, it does this even if I put an `autocomplete="off"` on the field.

So Firefox auto-filled the wrong form, which even have different field names (and differents fields id), with saved login informations. Is it a known-behavior ? is there a way to prevent it (as the autocomplete doesn't seems to do the job) ?

Just to prevent [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161485/firefox-fills-in-the-password-into-the-username-field), I removed multiple times all datas from Firefox's password manager, it's not about old stored fields names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I found a working answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/29852908/1459054

While searching, this "bug"... sorry, "feature", exists for more than 10 years in Firefox, I saw multiple bugs reports about this tagged "WONTFIX" because it's the expected behavior ("Password manager shouldn't rely on field names") that makes the login informations popin anywhere it can fit, and because "it doesn't concern many users, so its not important to fix".